# Concurrent Queue, C

Tags: c, concurrency

So, I am trying to implement a concurrent queue in C. I have split the methods into "read methods" and "write methods". So, when accessing the write methods, like push() and pop(), I acquire a writer lock. And the same for the read methods. Also, we can have several readers but only one writer.

In order to get this to work in code, I have a mutex lock for the entire queue. And two condition locks - one for the writer and the other for the reader. I also have two integers keeping track of the number of readers and writers currently using the queue.

So my main question is - how to implement several readers accessing the read methods at the same time?

At the moment this is my general read method code: (In psuedo code - not C. I am actually using pthreads).

```
mutex.lock();
while (nwriter > 0) {
  wait(&reader);
  mutex.unlock();
}
nreader++;
//Critical code
nreader--;
if (nreader == 0) {
  signal(&writer)
}
mutex.unlock
```

So, imagine we have a reader which holds the mutex. Now any other reader which comes along, and tries to get the mutex, would not be able to. Wouldn't it block? Then how are many readers accessing the read methods at the same time?

Is my reasoning correct? If yes, how to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to add a semaphore to the mix. And see http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Bjsessionid%3D1295096AC48D19D5028A2E5220AA8A86%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.148.428%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=concurrent%20control%20with%20readers%20and%20writers&ei=qorLTdGPF8-7hAe8jd2oAg&usg=AFQjCNFE4mls4bVwP7NpYw5tCfYek7aq2g&sig2=dg9OjLdU2Qypk33jAdHMIQ&cad=rja

Comment: I believe it is possible by just using condition variables. But if I have to make use of a semaphore, what would you say I should use it for?

Comment: The link is to a classic article describing the algorithm using a mutex and a semaphore.

Comment: Oh thankyou! I did not notice the link.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not for an exercise, use read-write lock from pthreads (`pthread_rwlock_*` functions).

Also note that protecting individual calls with a lock stil might not provide necessary correctness guarantees. For example, a typical code for popping an element from STL queue is

```
if( !queue.empty() ) {
    data = queue.top();
    queue.pop();
}
```

And this will fail in concurrent code even if locks are used inside the queue methods, because conceptually this code must be an atomic transaction, but the implementation does not provide such guarantees. A thread may pop a different element than it read by top(), or attempt to pop from empty queue, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following read\write functions.

In my functions, I used canRead and canWrite mutexes and nReads for number of readers:

Write function:

```
lock(canWrite) // Wait if mutex if not free
// Write
unlock(canWrite)
```

Read function:

```
lock(canRead) // This mutex protect the nReaders
nReaders++    // Init value should be 0 (no readers)
if (nReaders == 1) // No other readers
{
   lock(canWrite)  // No writers can enter critical section
}
unlock(canRead)

// Read

lock(canRead)
nReaders--;
if (nReaders == 0) // No more readers
{
   unlock(canWrite) // Writer can enter critical secion
}
unlock(canRead)
```

Comment: This code assumes that the lock can be acquired and released from different threads (for `canWrite` lock being used by readers), so might not work if the lock implementation does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

A classic solution is multiple-readers, single-writer.

A data structure begins with no readers and no writers.

You permit any number of concurrent readers.

When a writer comes along, you block him till all current readers complete; then you let him go (any new readers and writers which come along which the writer is blocked queue up behind him, in order).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this library it is built in c native, lock free, suitable for cross-platform [lfqueue](https://github.com/Taymindis/lfqueue),

For Example:-

```
int* int_data;
lfqueue_t my_queue;

if (lfqueue_init(&my_queue) == -1)
    return -1;

/** Wrap This scope in other threads **/
int_data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
assert(int_data != NULL);
*int_data = i++;
/*Enqueue*/
 while (lfqueue_enq(&my_queue, int_data) == -1) {
    printf("ENQ Full ?\n");
}

/** Wrap This scope in other threads **/
/*Dequeue*/
while  ( (int_data = lfqueue_deq(&my_queue)) == NULL) {
    printf("DEQ EMPTY ..\n");
}

// printf("%d\n", *(int*) int_data );
free(int_data);
/** End **/

lfqueue_destroy(&my_queue);
```